# Reference request: Concerning a connectivity property of a graph

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory, reference-request

**Introduction** 
The vertex connectivity $\kappa(G)$  of a connected graph $G$ is the minimum number of nodes whose deletion disconnects it. Similarly, the edge connectivity $\lambda (G)$ is   the minimum number of edges whose deletion disconnects it.

It is well known that for $d$-regular graph G we have,
$$\kappa(G)\leq \lambda(G)\leq d. $$

**Question?** This  [wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connectivity_(graph_theory)#Bounds_on_connectivity) states that for any symmetric connected graph of degree $d$ we have
 $$\kappa(G) = \lambda(G) = d.$$

None of the graph theory books that I know mention this theorem.

Could anyone please suggest a reference that mention this theorem? (book, survey,...)

Comment: At the very least the theorem (?) should add connectedness as a condition on the graph.

Comment: Here (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetric_graph#Properties) is a source for this claim, or at least part of it.

Comment: That wikipedia page in question gives a reference for this theorem https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connectivity_(graph_theory)#Bounds_on_connectivity, namely right here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connectivity_(graph_theory)#cite_note-7

Comment: @LeeMosher I look into this reference, it does not contain the above theorem.

Comment: @Bemte It seems that this reference doesn't contain the above theorem.

Comment: @MeesdeVries Yes, I edit the question. In fact, connectedness condition should  be added since the vertex and edge connectivity are only defined for connected graph.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Theorem 3.7 of [Automorphism groups, isomorphism, reconstruction](http://people.cs.uchicago.edu/~laci/handbook/handbookchapter27.pdf)
 by L. Babai shows that a digraph $G$ that is both vertex-transitive and edge-transitive with out-degree $d$ has $\kappa(G) = \lambda(G) = d$. Babai also notes that an undirected graph can be viewed as a directed graph with edges oriented both ways. This implies that for a symmetric undirected graph $G$ (which is both vertex-transitive and edge-transitive), we have $\kappa(G) = \lambda(G) = d$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer !